# <FloatField'> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am currently learning Django, i tried creating a simple model and expose it in an API.

> FloatField' is not JSON serializable

it only works if i change the float to string.

When i call the api to retreive the model object i receive error:

I defined the model as follows:

```
class RunSession(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   miles = models.FloatField
   duration = models.FloatField
   created=  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class RunSessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
     model = RunSession
     fields = ('created', 'name', 'miles', 'duration', )
```

ViewSet:

```
class RunSessionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

  queryset = RunSession.objects.order_by('created')
  serializer_class = RunSessionSerializer
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the original field objects and not instantiating them. Do instantiate them:

```
miles = models.FloatField(...)
#                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: thanks, i missed it, but when i instantiated it i got this error:could not convert string to float:.... should i change anything else from the code above?

Comment: You have strings for those fields in your JSON?

Comment: this is how i defined the serializer, without specifying field type

Comment: But this model `Acount` is different from the model  in the OP: `RunSession`. You should update the question or ask a new one

Comment: my bad, i pasted the wrong model in this comment, this is the model  class Meta:
     model = RunSession
     fields = ('created', 'name', 'miles', 'duration', )

Comment: I mean if the JSON contains a string for `miles`, you can't possibly use `FloatField` except you tweak the decoder or change the field type to a `CharField`